# cannondale cadd10 105 crankset replacement

Tags: chainring, crankset, replacement, cannondale

I had a terrible crash on my Cannondale CADD10 105 (11spd) and wrecked the crankset (the bigger ring bent). It is FSA Gossamer Pro, BB30, 52/36 from the website. Is there an identical one available for replacement? I couldn't find any on Amazon or online store.

And what does BB30 mean?

Thanks

Comment: If it's really just the chainring that's bent, you can replace just that part and keep the rest of the crank.

Comment: I also have a CAAD 10 (2015 disc model) that came with the FSA Gossamer mid-compact crank.  If I were you and had the means, the stock crank is one of the first things I'd upgrade, as it is heavy and not very stiff.  I've now ridden mine with a BB30 SRAM Red and it's a different machine.  Since you are running Shimano, I might look at getting an Ultegra crank.

Answer (score 1):

BB30 is Cannondale's (now open) standard for how the crankset fits into the frame.

Cannondale invented the [BB30](http://www.cannondale.com/uk_gb/innovation/bb30/) bottom bracket in 2000 and debuted it at the Tour De France (I couldn't find any information about how they faired) in 2006 the BB30 became an free international standard allowing any cycle manufacturer to use it.

> The BB30 International Standard provides the specifications for an oversized bottom bracket shell for a bike frame. This standard allows for Direct-fit, pressed-in bearings and a 30 mm spindle. The system saves weight by accepting a 30mm aluminum spindle and eliminating cups that would normally hold the bearings.

The claimed advantage of BB30 is an increase in stiffness and a 4% increase in drivetrain efficiency, achieved through an increase in size allowing larger diameter frame tubes. (according to [Cannondale](http://www.cannondale.com/uk_gb/innovation/bb30/) - I don't have the rep to comment!)

The [Caad10](http://www.cannondale.com/nam_en/2015/bikes/road/elite-road/caad10/caad10-5-105) uses 110 BCD 5 arm chainring, if you put that into your favourite search engine there are a large selection of chainrings that will be compatible. You don't specifically need to replace them with the same size chainring, you can change them depending on your requirements.

The Shimano 105 chainrings should be a direct replacement, and are relatively inexpensive. Personally I wouldn't try to straighten an old chainring, as the metal would have stretched and you are unlikely to get it back to being entirely flat.

Comment: "The claimed advantage of BB30 is an increase in stiffness and a 4% increase in drivetrain efficiency, achieved through an increase in size allowing larger diameter frame tubes."  Do you have the source of this info?

Answer (score 0):

BB30 is the type of [bottom bracket](http://www.bikeradar.com/us/gear/article/complete-guide-to-bottom-brackets-36660/) you use (so you need a 52/36 crankset which is for a BB30 bottom bracket). Many of the parts that ship with a bike are OEM only, but you can get compatible ones. If you're looking at FSA branded stuff, look for cranksets marked [BB386EVO](http://www.fullspeedahead.com/bottom-bracket-standards-demystified/).

You can try [straightening](http://sheldonbrown.com/straighten-chw.html) your existing chainrings with an crescent wrench in some cases or replace them, if thats where the damage is (as noted by Nik in the comments).

Edit: Yours is the semi-compact [FSA Gossamer Pro BB386 Evo](http://www.fullspeedahead.com/products/cranksets-road/gossamer-pro-compact-crankset-5034-5236-bb386evo/).